# Review manager/reviews manager

Tags: business-language

I work for a transcription company where my job is to both review files for accuracy and oversee and coordinate with other people who also will review files.  Is it more accurate to say that I am the Reviews Manager (Because I am overseeing all incoming reviews), or Review Manager (because I manage the review process)?  Or is there another title that would be more appropriate?

Comment: In a workplace scenario, you’d normally just use whatever title your boss sees fit to use. Director, manager, lead reviewer, etc. Hopefully, not just *hey, you*.